# neo4j list current node indexes

Tags: shell, neo4j, indexing

I was wonder if anyone could tell me how you list all the existing indexes on nodes in a neo4j database through the neo4j-sh shell?

The documentation shows how it can be done using the REST api http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-indexes.html

but how do I do it from the neo4j-sh shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index --indexes` should list all the Names indexes. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I was looking in the cypher documentation, when I should have been looking in the neo4j-sh documentation.

Comment: If I run it in from browser I get: Invalid input 'i': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0)) "index --indexes"